# Try to install youcompleteme plugin on vim error ./install.py no such file or directory

Tags: vim, plugins, c++

Try to install youcompleteme plugin on vim but I got error /.install.py [Errno 2] error no such file or directory.

I tried to follow the instructions https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py --clang-completer
```

but I got error in the second command. 
I had install python 3  and the version is python3.6
any suggestions?

Error that I got : python3: can't open file 'install.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I executed this command :sudo apt install build-essential cmake python3-dev
and installed vundle
but when i executed this command

cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py --clang-completer

I got error ins ./install.py, any suggestions?

Comment: python3: can't open file 'install.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory , this is the error i got

Comment: Does install.py even exist in the ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe directory? Have you looked?

Comment: @n8te it doesnt exist. that the error i got it says cant open file "install.py" , no such file or directory. though i tried to execute python3 install.py

Comment: If it doesn't exist in the directory, you can't run it. That's what the error message is telling you--you're trying to run a file that isn't there. Did you download all the files from the github link you provided?

Comment: yes, i tried to follow all the instructions. i installed python and cmake by execute "sudo apt install build-essential cmake python3-dev" but beside that error i  got  this error too "CMake Error: The source directory "/home/devina/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI."

Comment: You didn't clone the repo into the correct directory. That is why it can't find anything you're trying to run.

Comment: Do this: `cd ~/.vim/bundle && rm -r YouCompleteMe && git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe` ; then go back and run the two commands in your post above.